# Find pattern with Powershell and send email

Tags: powershell, select-string

I have a script that searches through xml files for a pattern and then a file is created with the results.  It then emails the file when the search finds a match.  However, this part is not working.  Any help would(or tweaks) would be amazing:

```
$date= Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd
$dir= "c:\test\$date"
$path=Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Recurse
$pattern = "<RESULT>FAILED</RESULT>"
$submitted = select-string -path $path -pattern $pattern | select Path,Filename | Export-Csv -Path "D:\Failed.csv"
if(@($submitted).Count -eq 0) {
##donothing 
}
else
           {
    Send-MailMessage -From "noreply@email.com" -To users@email.com -Subject "Failed Report" -Body "Attached are the failed files for App" -Attachments "D:\Failed.csv" -SmtpServer 0.0.0.0
    Remove-Item "D:\Failed.csv" -recurse
           }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is in below code line

```
$submitted = select-string -path $path -pattern $pattern | select Path,Filename | Export-Csv -Path "D:\Failed.csv"
```

Change it to two statements like

```
$submitted = (select-string -path $path -pattern $pattern | measure-object).Count

select-string -path $path -pattern $pattern | select Path,Filename | Export-Csv -Path "D:\Failed.csv"
```

then check for condition

```
if($submitted -eq 0) {
##donothing 
}
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you very much.  That worked accurately